# How to put "Tags" to Firefox's bookmark toolbar?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

When I press CTRL+SHIFT+O there is a "Tags" object containing all of my tags on the left. I want to use this as a folder on my bookmarks toolbar, so I can easily browse all bookmarks with the specific tag.

In the Bookmarks menu there is a "Recent tags" folder, but this does not contain all of my tags.

It think that keeping bookmarks in their folders AND tag them, but able to browse them by their tag(s) name(s) makes sense not only for the "Unsorted bookmarks" type (which aren't moved to a *specific* folder).

One bookmark can have several tags and a tag can belong to several bookmarked pages, no exception here from either point of view.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Open the Bookmarks Library Window by selecting Bookmarks, Show All Bookmarks.
2. Drag-and-drop the Tags item to the Bookmarks Toolbar Item. Or, drag individual tags to the bookmarks toolbar.

Comment: Shame myself. I've forgotten that firefox is the most customizable web browser, ever. I've overcomplicated this :)